# Будет ли заддосен сайт A, если на сайте B установлен js кода сайта A

Tags: ddos, php

Допустим сайт B поставил себе JS код сайта, который выполняет определенные функции на php и выдает определенный код, то есть импортируемый js файл не статичный. Если будут ддосить сайт B, то ляжет ли и сайт A? 
Если это так, то решением данной проблемы я так понял нужно делать кеширование данных js файлов?

Answer (score 3):

> Допустим сайт B поставил себе **JS код сайта**, который **выполняет** определенные **функции на php**

Каким образом это можно осуществить? JS файл должен выполнять только лишь JS код.
PHP-код выполняет php-интерпретатор, обрабатывая код в `<?php ?>` или других инструкциях.

> Если будут ддосить сайт B, то ляжет ли и сайт A?

DDOS-атака основывается на отправке огромного потока пакетов к серверу, на котором хостится сайт. Поэтому не ляжет сайт А, ибо страницы сайта B при атаке не будут даже парситься открываться/выполняться => не будет выполняться и ваш JS код с запросом к сайту А.

Comment: Ну не совсем... ДДоСить могут и конкретную службу, что, зная наших писателей веб-приложений, уже может оказать даже очень еффективно.

Что да сути вопроса - вряд ли. Проблемы с сайтом А будут только если ему очень-очень не повезет (другой сайт каким-то образом попадет в список засыраемых ресурсов).

Answer (score 0):

> Если будут ддосить сайт B, то ляжет ли и сайт A?

**Нет**. DDOS атака состоит не в загрузке веб-страницы со всеми линкованными из неё вспомогательными файлами с третих сайтов, а в бомбёжке веб сервера B запросами, часто даже не дожидаясь ответа.

> нужно делать кеширование данных js файлов

**Нужно**. Чтобы при повторных запросах с одинаковыми параметрами, определяющими содержание этого JS, выдавался не заново сгенерированный с помощью php, а закэшированный в памяти или на диске готовый JS.